# Autocomplete against geocode.arcgis.com?

Tags: geocoding, arcgis-online, arcgis-flex-api

I have built a tool that allows my users to perform geocode requests against the [World Geocoding Service](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/geocoding.html) provided from Esri.

I would like to extend my tool to have an autocomplete feature, similar to how this can be [achieved](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) with the [Autocomplete class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete) from the Google Geocode API.

Although there is not a similar class available at the Esri service end, I was thinking that you could still hit the geocode service with a GET request, after listening for a slight delay after each keystroke from the end-user in something like a combo-box, and just return the top 5 results based on score.

I am looking for an answer that provides some code (can be pseudocode, or any language) on how to accomplish this, or if this workflow is even achievable.  Something similar [to this](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4a61e3e4b0c94300a3a361855d9a344f), but against the Esri Geocode service as opposed to map services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can autocomplete against a geocode service.

Pseudo-code:

```
if >4 chars + keystroke + delay 300ms
  Send Geocode request using text=inputBox.value
```

Here is how it looks at the front-end:

[image]

It waits for user to type in 4 characters, then populates a [autocomplete flex component](http://hillelcoren.com/flex-autocomplete/documentation/) with the response.

When you choose an item from the dropdown, it zoom to the feature, and presents any additional results it found, using a green outline for high confident matches, and orange ones for lesser confident ones.

I have taken it a step further, and allowd the user to configure a bounding box, source country, state, and minimum candidate score within an XML file.

I need to tidy up some of the logic, and then I will try to put it into a flexviewer widget and upload to arcgis.com.

Comment: Just found this which looks awesome  https://github.com/Esri/geocoder-search-widget-js

Comment: There's also a javascript sample up here, which might be useful for others migrating from flex: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/locator_widget.html